# Vim matching braces confuses with strings contents

Tags: vim

Sometimes I have code like this:

```
json_encode([
    'token' => 'as!"·)#|@∞"'
]);
```

If I put the cursor on the first `[` and I press `%` the cursor mover to the matching `]`. But, if I put the cursor on the first `(` (at the left of `json_encode`), and press `%`, vim get confused, and fails at getting the matching character.

Vim thinks the matching character is the `)` inside the string on the second line.

This kind of stuff is language specific, so, is there any way to let vim know how to deal with specific language traits?

Answer (score 1):

The matching behavior of the `%` command can be controlled using `cpoptions` (vi compatibility options). If `%` is *not* in `cpoptions` vim should ignore parentheses in double or single quotes.

You can check the value of `cpoptions` using:

```
:set cpoptions?
```

If the `%` character is in `cpoptions` you can remove it using:

```
:set cpoptions-=%
```